# docker-compose: (root) Additional property webapi is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, open-source

i tried to install metasfresh erp and run into install issues.

Always when i try run `docker compose build` i get error messages like

`(root) Additional property app is not allowed` or

`(root) Additional property db is not allowed`

on Docker version 24.0.2 / Docker Compose version v2.12.2 - vServer Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Maybe someone can help. :)

Yamllint said valid:

```
---
db:
  build: db
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ./volumes/db/log:/var/log/postgresql
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    - METASFRESH_USERNAME=metasfresh
    - METASFRESH_PASSWORD=metasfresh
    - METASFRESH_DBNAME=metasfresh
    - DB_SYSPASS=System
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ip2LmNzXX8p8iXg9lZTWEJ9524kQDbXFudB7LR03T-xK9fLweX3TLMkA2AYcEiaS
app:
  build: app
  hostname: app
  links:
    - db:db
    - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
    - search:search
  expose:
    - "8282"
    - "8788"
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/app/log:/opt/metasfresh/log:rw
    - ./volumes/app/heapdump:/opt/metasfresh/heapdump:rw
    - ./volumes/app/external-lib:/opt/metasfresh/external-lib:rw
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    - METASFRESH_HOME=/opt/metasfresh
webapi:
  build: webapi
  links:
    - app:app
    - db:db
    - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
    - search:search
  expose:
    - "8789"
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/webapi/log:/opt/metasfresh-webui-api/log:rw
    - ./volumes/webapi/heapdump:/opt/metasfresh-webui-api/heapdump:rw
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
webui:
  build: webui
  links:
    - webapi:webapi
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    - WEBAPI_URL=http://erp.mydomain.com:80
rabbitmq:
  build: rabbitmq
  expose:
    - "5672"
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/rabbitmq/log:/var/log/rabbitmq/log
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: metasfresh
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: metasfresh
    RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: /
search:
  build: search
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536
  cap_add:
    - IPC_LOCK
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/search/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
  environment:
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx256m
  restart: always
```

Tried reinstall docker-compose and changed ports on docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

When compose gives an error like `Additional property app is not allowed` its telling you that the given label (app in this case) is defined at a level where it is expecting a fixed list of properties.

You have defined `app` in the root of the document. Looking at the compose spec, the root of a compose document expects a fixed list of properties, including `services`, `volumes` and some other similar things.

Consequently, your compose.yml should look like this at a high level:

```yaml
services:
  app:
  db:
  webapi:
  search:
```

I'll also say that "links" and "expose" are completely out of date and can be omitted.